# What is a 2-way heap?

Tags: c++, data-structures, dijkstra

I'm reading a book about AI and currently learning about pathfinding(currently doing the Dijkstra algorithm)

In the sample code he's using something he calls an IndexedPriorityQueue implemented as a two-way heap. I couldn't find any information on what a two-way heap is on google.

> This search algorithm is implemented using an indexed priority queue.
>   A priority queue, or PQ for short, is a queue that keeps its elements
>   sorted in order of priority (no surprises there then). This type of
>   data structure can be utilized to store the destination nodes of the
>   edges on the search frontier, in order of increasing distance (cost)
>   from the source node. This method guarantees that the node at the
>   front of the PQ will be the node not already on the SPT that is
>   closest to the source node.

This is how it gets implemented:

```
//----------------------- IndexedPriorityQLow ---------------------------
//
//  Priority queue based on an index into a set of keys. The queue is
//  maintained as a 2-way heap.
//
//  The priority in this implementation is the lowest valued key
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<class KeyType>
class IndexedPriorityQLow
{
private:

  std::vector<KeyType>&  m_vecKeys;

  std::vector<int>       m_Heap;

  std::vector<int>       m_invHeap;

  int                    m_iSize,
                         m_iMaxSize;

  void Swap(int a, int b)
  {
    int temp = m_Heap[a]; m_Heap[a] = m_Heap[b]; m_Heap[b] = temp;

    //change the handles too
    m_invHeap[m_Heap[a]] = a; m_invHeap[m_Heap[b]] = b;
  }

  void ReorderUpwards(int nd)
  {
    //move up the heap swapping the elements until the heap is ordered
    while ( (nd>1) && (m_vecKeys[m_Heap[nd/2]] > m_vecKeys[m_Heap[nd]]) )
    {      
      Swap(nd/2, nd);

      nd /= 2;
    }
  }

  void ReorderDownwards(int nd, int HeapSize)
  {
    //move down the heap from node nd swapping the elements until
    //the heap is reordered
    while (2*nd <= HeapSize)
    {
      int child = 2 * nd;

      //set child to smaller of nd's two children
      if ((child < HeapSize) && (m_vecKeys[m_Heap[child]] > m_vecKeys[m_Heap[child+1]]))
      {
        ++child;
      }

      //if this nd is larger than its child, swap
      if (m_vecKeys[m_Heap[nd]] > m_vecKeys[m_Heap[child]])
      {
        Swap(child, nd);

        //move the current node down the tree
        nd = child;
      }

      else
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }


public:

  //you must pass the constructor a reference to the std::vector the PQ
  //will be indexing into and the maximum size of the queue.
  IndexedPriorityQLow(std::vector<KeyType>& keys,
                      int              MaxSize):m_vecKeys(keys),
                                                m_iMaxSize(MaxSize),
                                                m_iSize(0)
  {
    m_Heap.assign(MaxSize+1, 0);
    m_invHeap.assign(MaxSize+1, 0);
  }

  bool empty()const{return (m_iSize==0);}

  //to insert an item into the queue it gets added to the end of the heap
  //and then the heap is reordered from the bottom up.
  void insert(const int idx)
  {
    assert (m_iSize+1 <= m_iMaxSize);

    ++m_iSize;

    m_Heap[m_iSize] = idx;

    m_invHeap[idx] = m_iSize;

    ReorderUpwards(m_iSize);
  }

  //to get the min item the first element is exchanged with the lowest
  //in the heap and then the heap is reordered from the top down. 
  int Pop()
  {
    Swap(1, m_iSize);

    ReorderDownwards(1, m_iSize-1);

    return m_Heap[m_iSize--];
  }

  //if the value of one of the client key's changes then call this with 
  //the key's index to adjust the queue accordingly
  void ChangePriority(const int idx)
  {
    ReorderUpwards(m_invHeap[idx]);
  }
};
```

Can anyone give me more information on what a 2-way heap is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Two-way heap" simply refers to the standard [heap data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). This code shows a very common way of implementing it, namely by flattening the tree structure of the heap into an array, in such a way that the index of a node's parent is always half of the index of the node (rounded down).

Comment: @xcrypt: Not sure what happened there, but I did initially have an erroneous link, and someone probably corrected it in the background while I made another edit, which overwrote the first edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is implemented AS a two way heap because he omits the 0 index in the heap to make parent- child calculation easier but the key values vektor begins at 0 index so inverted heap is storing indexes that keys to   heap witch stores indexes that keys to keyVector  to get appropriate value from keyVector you will need to do something like this  keyVector[heap[invHeap[itemIndex] ] ]  the rest of the code is just standard binary heap implementation.